# Does mlflow support cluster deployment?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deployment, mlflow

We would like to develop an ML platform contains mlflow. We have read the [official doc](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/quickstart.html), but it only tell us how to deploy on a single node. If this node crashed, the tracking service could be down, so I want to know if there is anyway to deploy a cluster of mlflow?

Comment: In this thread talks about how to provide high availability to MLFlow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481147/mlflow-registry-high-availability

Comment: Yes, thank you @dgrana